# Using super class

Tags: java

We know when a base class is inherited by a derived class that is called inheritance and when a derived class contains same method name, return type and argument list as like as base class's method that is called method overriding. 
And we also know that The super keyword can  be used to invoke base class method. It should be used if derived class contains the same method as base class. In other words, it is used if method is overridden.

But my code doesn't work perfectly, why????? Help me please..........

```
 public class person {
  String name = "Mohan";
  int age = 24;

  void displayInformation() {
   displayInformation();
   System.out.println("Name: " + name);
   System.out.println("Age: " + age);
  }
 }

 public class teacher extends person {

  String qualification = "B.Sc in CSE";


  @Override
  void displayInformation() {
   super.displayInformation();
   System.out.println("Name: " + name);
   System.out.println("Age: " + age);
   System.out.println("Qualification: " + qualification);
  }
 }
 public class MethodOverriding {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   teacher t = new teacher();
   t.displayInformation();

  }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What behaviour do you expect?
Also you may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and include the code in the question with proper markup and not in an external link.

Comment: Learn from https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you ask a question

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct. In the code of `person` is a mistake:

```
void displayInformation() {
  displayInformation();
```

You guide the method `displayInformation` call first the method `displayInformation` who calls first the method `displayInformation` who calls first the method `displayInformation` (...).

You will end-up in a Exception.

Remove the call of `displayInformation` in the class `person` and the Exception will go away.

Comment: Funnily enough it will be a StackOverflow exception, so he's in the right place!!  ;-)

Comment: @Rick Yea :D I thought to point that out, but if it rans into a OOME the joke wont work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detecting my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that instead of this:

```
@Override
void displayInformation() {
  super.displayInformation();
  System.out.println("Name: " + name);
  System.out.println("Age: " + age);
  System.out.println("Qualification: " + qualification);
}
```

you want:

```
@Override
void displayInformation() {
  super.displayInformation();
  System.out.println("Qualification: " + qualification);
}
```

Otherwise name and age are printed twice.  Once when you call the parent-class method and then again in the child-class implementation.

Comment: Also note that if you didn't have super. in the subclass implementation then you'd have an infinite loop, and that would be bad (TM).

Comment: Lol.  Totally missed that you already had an infinite loop at the higher level too.  Wheee!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class person {
String name = "Mohan";
int age = 24`enter code here`;

void displayInformation()
{
    //displayInformation();
    System.out.println("Name: " +name);
    System.out.println("Age: " +age);
}
}

public class teacher extends person{

String qualification = "CSE";
@Override
void displayInformation()
{
    super.displayInformation();
    System.out.println("Name: " +name);
    System.out.println("Age: " +age);
    System.out.println("Qualification: " +qualification);
}
}

public class teacher extends person{

String qualification = "CSE";
@Override
void displayInformation()
{
    super.displayInformation();
    System.out.println("Name: " +name);
    System.out.println("Age: " +age);
    System.out.println("Qualification: " +qualification);
}
}

public class MethodOverriding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    teacher t = new teacher();
    t.displayInformation();

}
}
```